# special character not visible in the database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

There is some special character in my one of my data field. I need to know what is it. I know it's not space.

The select query returns akasa and akasa. There are 2 same entries on a defined primary column.

```
Select userid from users where userid like 'akasa%'.
```

When I use the `len` function in the query it is showing length as 5 and 7. It means these are different values.

when I use the command

```
Select userid from users where userid='akasa  '.
```

It doesn't show anything which means it is not space.

So, I realized there are 2 special characters which are not visible and I need to know what are they ? What can I use to detect them ?

Comment: How are you performing these queries? The problem probably lies in whatever GUI you are looking at results in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would first ask *why* you want to know what it is. If the intent is to simply get rid of or turn it into something else, the row can be selected with:

```
... where userid like 'akasa%' and userid <> 'akasa'
```

For example, to delete it, just use `delete` with that clause.

Alternatively, if you *do* need to know exactly what they are, write a little Java/JDBC or C#/ODBC program to retrieve the row using that `where` clause and you should be able to print out the real column value in any form you want, such as hex representation.

Comment: Thanks !! Yeah I can simply delete it. But, just out of the curiousity I was asking how to detect it.

Answer (score 3):

To inspect individual characters, you can use [`ASCII`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177545.aspx):

> Returns the ASCII code value of the leftmost character of a character expression.

and [`SUBSTRING`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx):

> Returns part of a character, binary, text, or image expression

E.g.

```
SELECT ASCII(SUBSTRING(userid,6,1))
```

will tell you what the 6th character is, precisely.

If I had to guess though, I'm guessing you'll find Carriage Return and Line Feed (ASCII values 13, 10)

Here's an [ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/) for reference.

Comment: Thanks. I have found 32 and 13 values  in first one and 32 and 32 in the second one.  32 is represn